# jQuery possible bloated code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was throwing together an animated navbar with jQuery and it seems like a lot of js for what I am trying to accomplish, anyone know of a more elegant solution for this effect?

Live Site:

http://daveywhitney.com/nav/2/

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#topnav li").prepend("<span></span>"); 

    $("#topnav li").each(function() { 
        var linkText = $(this).find("a").html(); 
        $(this).find("span").show().html(linkText); 
    }); 

    $("#topnav li").hover(function() {  
        $(this).find("span").stop().animate({
            marginTop: "-45" 
        }, 250);
    } , function() { 
        $(this).find("span").stop().animate({
            marginTop: "0"  
        }, 250);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do it in CSS using image sprites and `background-position`. That would cut out all the jQuery.

Comment: Thanks I will for sure check that out, although I worry about browser compatibility. Or do I....

Comment: It's supported in IE6+ and was part of the CSS2.1 spec.

Answer (score 2):

I don't find your code complicated or un-elegant at all.
However, if you want a different approach, you can try css3 animations.
[Here is a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/Jebh3/) of your effect with no js at all.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This is totally awesome but why does is switch back to red after the animation completes?

Answer (score 1):

you can skip 1 loop :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#topnav li").html(function(){
        var $obj= $(this);
        $obj.prepend('<span>'+$obj.find('a').html()+'</span>');
    });



    $("#topnav li").hover(function() {
        $(this).find("span").stop().animate({
            marginTop: "-45"
        }, 250);
    }, function() {
        $(this).find("span").stop().animate({
            marginTop: "0"
        }, 250);
    });

});
```

[**Click Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/Gd9Yf/1/)

But I Agree as well with **Andrew Peacock**, I would use the same animation in sprites,  leaving the same text and changing just background position. So you will skip 1 more loop to clone the text